# Emacs GUI for Mac, linux and windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

I'd like to start using emacs but I want also a GUI in which it will be available in windows, ubuntu linux (desktop) and  mac osx. Is GNU/Emacs capable for this? What other choices are there and how different is for each OS?

Also is there any disadvantages of using emacs with gui (for example, I can't use some kind of widgets or use something else) and how most other programmers prefer to use emacs? I want to use it as a replacement for textmate for ruby on rails development, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs has a native GUI version of GTK+(GNOME's toolkit), OSX with Cocoa from Emacs 23+(there is used to be Carbon Emacs before that, but it's now en route to oblivion) and Windows version.

I personally use emacs in daemon mode(emacs --daemon) and use emacslient to connect terminal and X clients to the daemon. I spend most of the time in a X frame though, I find  that much more productive - instead of running Emacs in a terminal like many people do, I run my terminal in Emacs. I don't used menus/toolbars - just a naked frame most of the time, split into many windows.

For rails development with Emacs you should have a look at [rinari](http://rinari.rubyforge.org/) and [nxhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html).

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  There is a Windows version of emacs, and you can use the X-windows interface on both linux and OS X.  There are also several different versions with native OS X GUIs.

Emacs is essentially a terminal-based program; there are no real disadvantages to having it running in a nice window, and the advantage of using mouse clicks and the menus.

Comment: If your source code needs inline images and pdfs, you're probably doing something wrong ;)

Comment: I disagree, with the second part of your answer. Actually there are a lot of advantages of running Emacs in X.

Comment: Bozhidar: Wooble didn't claim otherwise.

Comment: You can also use the X Window interface under Windows, using Cygwin (which provides the X.org server -- handy for both native Cygwin apps, and for providing a display for remote apps).

Comment: @Wooble: you're not necessarily doing anything wrong if you want inline images, a la auctex: http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/img/preview-screenshot.png